# Is there anything in the FTP protocol like the HTTP Range header?

Tags: http, ftp, protocols

Suppose I want to transfer just a portion of a file over FTP - is it possible using a standard FTP protocol?

In HTTP I could use a [Range header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716680/difference-between-content-range-and-range-headers) in the request to specify the data range of the remote resource.  If it's a 1mb file, I could ask for the bytes from 600k to 700k.

Is there anything like that in FTP?  I am reading [the FTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959), don't see anything, but want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

There's a Restart command in FTP - would that work?

---

**Addendum**
After getting [Brian Bondy's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538613/is-there-anything-in-the-ftp-protocol-like-the-http-range-header/2538739#2538739), I wrote a read-only Stream class that wraps FTP.  It supports Seek() and Read() operations on a resource that is read via FTP, based on the `REST` verb.
Find it at http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=streams&file=FtpReadStream.cs

It's pretty slow to Seek(), because setting up the data socket takes a long time.  Best results come when you wrap that stream in a [BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx).

Comment: This capability was suggested: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-bryan-ftp-range-00.txt but evidently never accepted.  There is a bit more information here:  https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2010/12/20/byte-ranges-for-ftp/
I guess the use cases for this are far and few between.  I wanted to use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can use the `REST` command.

`REST` sets the point at which a subsequent file transfer should start.  It is used usually for restarting interrupted transfers.   The command must come right before a `RETR` or `STOR` and so come after a `PORT` or `PASV`.

**From FTP's RFC 959:**

> RESTART (REST) The argument field
>   represents the server marker at which
>   file transfer is to be restarted. This
>   command does not cause file transfer
>   but skips over the file to the
>   specified data checkpoint. This
>   command shall be immediately followed
>   by the appropriate FTP service command
>   which shall cause file transfer to
>   resume.
>
> Read more:
>   http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html#ixzz0jZp8azux

Comment: Excellent. That sets the beginning of the range, which is the first half of the answer.  Setting the end of the range to transfer is the other half.  I don't think anything exists in FTP to do that, so... I suppose the client needs to just *stop transferring*.   Maybe send an Abort command.  Need to test.

Comment: @Cheeso: Yes that is correct you would simply send an ABOR or disconnect the data connection once you have enough data.

Comment: After trying this out, it seems to be working correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out how [GridFTP](http://dev.globus.org/wiki/GridFTP) does parallel transfers. That's using the sort of techniques that you want (and might actually be code that it is better to borrow rather than implementing from scratch yourself).