# Linux library for segmented download

Tags: linux, download, download-manager

I want to develop a download manager supporting segmented download. So, I am looking for a library supporting the same. Please give suggestions regarding the best library available on Linux platform that could serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any library that supports custom HTTP headers, such as [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), will work.

You need to spawn several threads. In each thread, set the `Range` field in you request header to specify which part of the file this thread needs to download.

And for [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) specially, you can use the `CURLOPT_RANGE` option to do partial file download.

See the description form [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)'s [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html).

> **CURLOPT_RANGE**
>
> Pass a char * as parameter, which should contain the specified range you want. It should be in the format "X-Y", where X or Y may be left out. HTTP transfers also support several intervals, separated with commas as in "X-Y,N-M". Using this kind of multiple intervals will cause the HTTP server to send the response document in pieces (using standard MIME separation techniques). For RTSP, the formatting of a range should follow RFC 2326 Section 12.29. For RTSP, byte ranges are not permitted. Instead, ranges should be given in npt, utc, or smpte formats.
>
> Pass a NULL to this option to disable the use of ranges.
>
> Ranges work on HTTP, FTP, FILE (since 7.18.0), and RTSP (since 7.20.0) transfers only.

Comment: I believe the request header field is `Range` not `Content-Range` [ref](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2) and [see also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716680/difference-between-content-range-and-range-headers)