# Indirect download link + download manager

Tags: php

In my site there are few posts that have files attached for VIP users. Because i wanna have control over the credits that let them download files, I made indirect URLs.

For example this link:

`http://mywebsite.com/file/file.zip`

can be downloaded by this:

`http://mywebsite.com/?download=1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f`

But a problem is that, files sizes are big and i need users can download them via a download manager, and as i know indirect download links couldn't be downloaded like that.

What's the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

why indirect  couldn't be downloaded like that?

you must program download program for resume ability search for `Content-Range` http header that is for resume

see this link can help you

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/209529-download-with-speed-limit-and-resume/

http://www.justskins.com/forums/php-getting-download-resume-120719.html

http://www.richnetapps.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option/

[Difference between Content-Range and Range headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716680/difference-between-content-range-and-range-headers)