# Large video Transfer via HTTP

Tags: python, http, python-requests, fastapi

The problem is I have to send a large video file to a web server.

The web server I am using is based on FastAPI and the client is the Python Requests library.

I did many research and can't able to find a good reliable way to send video to the server. The video size I am expecting is around 50MB.

Please help me to find a reliable method to send the file to server.

Comment: Regular HTTP POST with `UploadFile` in FastAPI doesn't work? What did you try that didn't work, and why didn't it work as you expected?

Comment: HTTP upload file is a good option. But if the internet went down, then I have to start over the entire file

Comment: There is no standardized way of handling partial uploads over HTTP; you'll have to come up with your own way depending on which requirements you have (you didn't mention partial uploads in your question, so it's hard to give any good advice when the requirements are unknown). There's a bit of discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969331/standard-method-for-http-partial-upload-resume-upload - implementing it as a PATCH request seems the most logical. But it'll be up to you how to determine what has been sent and what is still missing.