# How to Update a resource with a large attachment with PUT request in JAX-RS?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, attachment, put

I have a large `byte` file (log file) that I want to upload to server using `PUT` request. The reason I choose `PUT` is simply because I can use it to create a new resource or update an existing resource.

My problem is how to handle situation when server or Network disruption happens during PUT request.
That is say I have a huge file, during the transfer of which, Network failure happens. When the network resumes, I dont want to start the entire upload. How would I handle this?
I am using `JAX-RS` API with `RESTeasy` implementation.

Comment: This basically boils down to: "How resume a PUT to a Servlet after network failure?" HTTP supports `100 continue` for PUT but I am not sure if that can be used with JAX-RS implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Some people are using the `Content-Range` Header to achieve this but many people (like Mark Nottingham) state that this is not legal for requests. Please read the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6711496).

Besides there is no support from JAX-RS for this scenario.

If you really have the repeating problem of broken `PUT` requests I would simply let the client slice the files:

```
PUT /logs/{id}/1
PUT /logs/{id}/2
PUT /logs/{id}/3
```

`GET /logs/{id}` would then return the aggregation of all successful submitted slices.