# Problem with content range with Indy TIdHttp put command against MS Graph API

Tags: delphi, microsoft-graph-api, indy, idhttp

I am trying to use `TIdHttp.Put()` for Microsoft's [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-large-attachments?tabs=http), but it is not possible to use the `Content-Range` header. If I use the `Ranges` property then I get an error about a missing `Content-Range`, and if I use this header in the `CustomHeaders` property then I get an error about an invalid `Content-Range`.

Here is the code:

```pascal
sUploadSession := jsnUSession.Get('uploadUrl').JsonValue.Value;
Form1.htp2.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
Form1.htp2.Request.ContentLength := iSize;          //  3820753
Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
//Form1.htp.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Content-Length: ' + IntToStr(iSize));
Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Content-Range: bytes 0-' + IntToStr(iSize - 1) + '/' + IntToStr(iSize));   //  'Content-Range: bytes 0-3820750/3820751'
{with Form1.htp2.Request.Ranges.Add do
begin
  StartPos := 0;
  EndPos := iSize;
  s := Text; 
end;   }
fs := TStringStream.Create('{' + TEncoding.Default.GetString(TFile.ReadAllBytes(sFile)) + '}');
bLog := True;
try
  Form1.htp2.Put(sUploadSession, fs);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    Form1.RichEdit1.Lines.Add(E.Message + #13#10 + E.ErrorMessage);
end;
```

The message when I use the `Ranges` property is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"error":{"code":"MissingContentRangeHeader","message":"Content-Range header is required."}}
```

The message with `Content-Range` in `CustomHeaders` is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"error":{"code":"InvalidContentRangeHeader","message":"Invalid Content-Range header."}}
```

Is the `PUT` command in Indy compatible with the standard in HTTP, or is it necessary to make tweaks to have it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Range` and `Content-Range` HTTP headers are two completely different things.  See [Difference between Content-Range and Range headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716680/)

`Content-Range` is for specifying the range of bytes that are in the body of the same message that contains the `Content-Range` header.

The `Range` header is for *requesting* a range of bytes from the server.  The response message will indicate, via its own `Content-Range`, the actual range being sent in the response body.

So, that explains why you are getting a "missing `Content-Range`" error when using the `TIdHTTP.Ranges` property.  That property is simply not intended for the purpose you are using it for.

As for using the `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders` property to send a `Content-Range` header, that is the correct way to go (technically, `TIdEntityHeaderInfo` has `ContentRange...` properties, but they are currently only used by `TIdHTTP.Response`, not by `TIdHTTP.Request` - [that needs to be fixed](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/381)).

The problem with your custom `Content-Range` header is that the server is simply rejecting it as bad.  Which most likely means that the `iSize` value you are using doesn't actually match the number of bytes you are actually sending.

Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
sUploadSession := jsnUSession.Get('uploadUrl').JsonValue.Value;
fs := TStringStream.Create('{' + TEncoding.Default.GetString(TFile.ReadAllBytes(sFile)) + '}');
try
  bLog := True;
  try
    iSize := fs.Size; // <-- the TStringStream constructor internally converted the String to TBytes...
    Form1.htp2.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
    Form1.htp2.Request.ContentLength := iSize;
    Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Content-Range: bytes 0-' + IntToStr(iSize - 1) + '/' + IntToStr(iSize));

    Form1.htp2.Put(sUploadSession, fs);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      Form1.RichEdit1.Lines.Add(E.Message + #13#10 + E.ErrorMessage);
  end;
finally
  fs.Free;
end;
```

However, there is no good reason to read a file into a decoded UTF-16 `string` just to convert it back to bytes for transmission, so just send the original file bytes as-is instead, eg:

```pascal
sUploadSession := jsnUSession.Get('uploadUrl').JsonValue.Value;
fs := TFileStream.Create(sFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
try
  bLog := True;
  try
    iSize := fs.Size;
    Form1.htp2.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
    Form1.htp2.Request.ContentLength := iSize;
    Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Content-Range: bytes 0-' + IntToStr(iSize - 1) + '/' + IntToStr(iSize));

    Form1.htp2.Put(sUploadSession, fs);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      Form1.RichEdit1.Lines.Add(E.Message + #13#10 + E.ErrorMessage);
  end;
finally
  fs.Free;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
sUploadSession := jsnUSession.Get('uploadUrl').JsonValue.Value;
fs := TBytesStream.Create(TFile.ReadAllBytes(sFile));
try
  bLog := True;
  try
    iSize := fs.Size;
    Form1.htp2.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
    Form1.htp2.Request.ContentLength := iSize;
    Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Content-Range: bytes 0-' + IntToStr(iSize - 1) + '/' + IntToStr(iSize));

    Form1.htp2.Put(sUploadSession, fs);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      Form1.RichEdit1.Lines.Add(E.Message + #13#10 + E.ErrorMessage);
  end;
finally
  fs.Free;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```pascal
sUploadSession := jsnUSession.Get('uploadUrl').JsonValue.Value;
fs := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  bLog := True;
  try
    fs.LoadFromFile(sFile);
    fs.Position := 0;
    iSize := fs.Size;
    Form1.htp2.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
    Form1.htp2.Request.ContentLength := iSize;
    Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    Form1.htp2.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Content-Range: bytes 0-' + IntToStr(iSize - 1) + '/' + IntToStr(iSize));

    Form1.htp2.Put(sUploadSession, fs);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      Form1.RichEdit1.Lines.Add(E.Message + #13#10 + E.ErrorMessage);
  end;
finally
  fs.Free;
end;
```

Either way, do be aware that Microsoft recommends NOT uploading more than 4MB at a time when using this `PUT` API.  Your example file is 3.6MB, so it will just fit inside a single `PUT` request, but just know that for larger files, you are going to have to break them up into multiple 4MB uploads, paying attention to the `NextExpectedRanges` field in each successful response.

Comment: It works. I used the TMemoryStream alternative as it should be the most efficient and problem solved. Thanks  Remy..

Comment: Personally, I would have used a `TFileStream` instead, reading the stream in 4MB blocks and uploading each block, until the stream is exhausted. That way, large files can be uploaded without wasting lots of memory.